# Django queryset update migration

Tags: mysql, django, migration, django-queryset

I'm trying to optimize a migration, it's taking too long, about 15 minutes every time you try to run it, because there is a lot of data on this table. It's an old database that have dates like this '14102019' (%d%m%Y) as String, and need to convert them to DateField. I created a DateField for both.

Database is MySQL.

`dtobito` and `dtnasc` are the old strings that need to be converted

`data_obito` and `data_nasc` are the new DateFields

What works (very slowly):

```
def date_to_datefield(apps, schema_editor):
    Obitos = apps.get_model('core', 'Obitos')

    for obito in Obitos.objects.all():
        if obito.dtnasc and obito.dtnasc != '':
            obito.data_nasc = datetime.strptime(obito.dtnasc, '%d%m%Y')
        if obito.dtobito and obito.dtobito != '':
            obito.data_obito = datetime.strptime(obito.dtobito, '%d%m%Y')
        obito.save()
```

What doesn't work:

```
Obitos.objects.update(
    data_nasc=datetime.strptime(F('dtnasc'), '%d%m%Y'),
    data_obito=datetime.strptime(F('dtobito'), '%d%m%Y')
)
```

What could work, but I don't know how:

```
Obitos.objects.raw("""
        UPDATE obitos new,
        (
            SELECT 
                STR_TO_DATE(dtnasc, '%d%m%Y') AS dtnasc,
                STR_TO_DATE(dtobito, '%d%m%Y') AS dtobito,
            FROM obitos
        ) old
        SET new.data_nasc = old.dtnasc
        SET new.data_obtio = old.dtobito
    """)
```

Comment: Can you use [`bulk_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) (available from Django 2.2)?

Comment: @Ivan I didn't notice major improvements. But it helps a little I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `bulk_update`:

```
def date_to_datefield(apps, schema_editor):
    Obitos = apps.get_model('core', 'Obitos')

    objs = []

    def to_date_object(date_string):
        return datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d%m%Y')

    for obito in Obitos.objects.all():
        updated = False
        if obito.dtnasc:
            obito.data_nasc = to_date_object(obito.dtnasc)
            updated = True
        if obito.dtobito:
            obito.data_obito = to_date_object(obito.dtobito)
            updated = True
        if updated:
            objs.append(obito)

    if objs:
        Obitos.objects.bulk_update(objs, ['data_nasc', 'data_obito'])
```